# Passing data to Android Facebook default applicaiton

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to post messages to facebook wall using Android's default Facebook client. When i try to do so i am unable to post any text messages using the same. If i pass an URL it is extracting details like the title,image and description,etc from it and posts on the wall automatically.

How could i pass text to it. I am using the following lines of code to do it.When i do so the facebook application shows an error message "Your link could not be shared".

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, ""); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
String tst="This is a sample message via Public Intent";
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, tst);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

Comment: can any one help me out please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use facebook api in android named fbconnectandroid

Comment: Yes i know it is possible to use API but the requirement is such that i need to use facebook apps available on device to post messages

Comment: it is possibile with that API.i had done a similar appliacation like dis